# Sum multiple inputbox values

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of inputboxes with the class "selectme quantity" and would like to sum the amount of all together.

For example:

```
<input class="selectme quantity" value="4">
<input class="selectme quantity" value="1">
<input class="selectme quantity" value="5">
```

How can I run through all these inputs and display the total value (it would be 10)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function summate (selector) {
    var sum = 0;
    $(selector).each(function(){
        sum += parseFloat(this.value) || 0;
    });
    return sum;
}

 summate('.selectme.quantity');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K3z73/).

Or, if you're working with a browser that supports `Array.reduce()`:

```
var sum = $('.selectme.quantity').map(function(){
    return this.value && parseFloat(this.value);
}).get().reduce(function(a,b){
    return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
});

console.log(sum);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K3z73/1/).

References:

- [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a little jQuery plugin for this, if it is something you'll do frequently on the page and need some flexibility:

In this example, I am treating your quantities as integers -- that is, whole numbers. If you need to allow fractional quantities (ie: 3.5, 1.002, etc), you should use `parseFloat` rather than `parseInt` (thanks to David Thomas for the note!).

Using your example HTML:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        addElementValues: function() {
            var sum = 0;
            this.each(function() {
                sum += (typeof this.value != 'undefined' ? parseInt(this.value, 10) : 0);
            });
            return sum;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

console.log($('.selectme').addElementValues()); // 10
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/NhLBA/1/

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.fn.extend` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/
- `jQuery.each` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
- `parseInt` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: If you're going to use `parseInt()` then remember to use the radix (even if only to be over-cautious). Also, using `parseInt()` requires advance warning not to use floats.

Comment: Fair point, however, the use case appears to be in the context of order quantity, which is why I went for integers rather than floats. Even so, if he were dealing with something that was sold in a divisible unit (grams, for example), it may be an issue. I'll edit my answer to note that.